# Boto3 Cloudtrail returns no events for a resource

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

I am trying to get events like (runinstances,createtags & terminateinstances) from cloudtrail for a instance id through boto3, below is my code

```
import boto3

cloudtrail = boto3.client('cloudtrail')

instance_id = 'i-0002e660b987688'

starttime = '2020-04-01'
endtime = '2020-04-03'


try:
    response = cloudtrail.lookup_events(
        LookupAttributes=[
            {
                'AttributeKey': 'ResourceName',
                'AttributeValue': instance_id
            },
        ],
        StartTime=starttime,
        EndTime=endtime,
        MaxResults=50
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise(e)

print(response)
```

I am not getting any events , where as from AWS console I can see all those events for the time period specified above.

> {u'Events': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0,
>   'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '658e4873-b0d1-453c',
>   'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '658e4873-b0d1-453', 'date': 'Fri,
>   03 Apr 2020 03:53:57 GMT', 'content-length': '13', 'content-type':
>   'application/x-amz-json-1.1'}}}

Answer (score 0):

Seems like removing endtime worked for me , not sure why though.

I can able to get the desired events now.

```
try:
    response = cloudtrail.lookup_events(
        LookupAttributes=[
            {
                'AttributeKey': 'ResourceName',
                'AttributeValue': instance_id
            },
        ],
        StartTime=starttime,
        #EndTime=endtime,
        MaxResults=50
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise(e)

print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the shutdown time is greater than the system time setting in your environment, the corresponding error may be output.

The standard time parameter must be in the format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`.